# Run MySQL queries for Chatterbot

Tags: mysql, django, chatterbot

I've built a chatterbot application which takes user input and responds based on bestmatch algorithm. Curently its working only till picking the responses from the corpus or text file.

I want my chatbot to interact with MySQL database. I'm using chatterbot modules. Since chatterbot wont support mysql drectly, I changed settings.py, added MySQL details. As per the document link I followed 'https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04' I performed 'python36 manage.py makemigrations'.

### settings.py:

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'database_name',
        'USER': 'user_name',
        'PASWORD': 'pwd',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        }
}`

I do not know further steps on making my chatbot to query the database I mentioned and respond to the end user based on the input. Can you please suggest me some learning path or can you please let me know how do I achieve it? .

Regards,
Hari

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? Can you show us some code? Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Shanteshwar, I've added few more details. Hope the problem is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your database name in `'NAME' : 'database_name',` user name should be root and password should be empty

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testingDjangoApp',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```